# Selenium how can i locate multiple (second,third,fourth,etc) elements with the same class name by class_name in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i just want to know how to call the next table with the same class name 'linescores-table' because only got the first one and i can go through to the second table

i tried to make this code but it fetch error. putting s in element

```
[table = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("linescores-table")]
```

this is the table i want to scrape both with selenium
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRcY5.png

full code here, You can try in your own to understand my problem carefully

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path_to_chromedriver = 'chromedriver.exe' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/scores/01/23/2019'
driver.get(url)

table = driver.find_element_by_class_name("linescores-table")

team1_quarter_score= []
team2_quarter_score= []

for line_id,lines in enumerate(table.text.split('\n')):
    if line_id == 0:
        column_names = lines.split(' ')[1:]
    else:
        if line_id % 2 == 1:
            team1_quarter_score.append(lines.split(' '))
        if line_id % 2 == 0:
            team2_quarter_score.append(lines.split(' '))

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'teams': [i[0] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'standing': [i[1] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'q1': [i[2] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'q2': [i[3] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'q3': [i[4] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'q4': [i[5] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'finalScore':[i[6] for i in team1_quarter_score]
                                                  }
                     )
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'teams': [i[0] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'standing': [i[1] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'q1': [i[2] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'q2': [i[3] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'q3': [i[4] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'q4': [i[5] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'finalScore':[i[6] for i in team2_quarter_score]
                                                  }
                     )
df=df1.append(df2)
print(df)
```

expect to collect all the data's in the second table with the same class name but i only get the first table.

this is the actual output of the code.

```
  teams standing  q1  q2  q3  q4 finalScore
0   TOR    36-14  16  31  28  31        106
1   IND    32-15  24  35  25  26        110
```

my expected output will be 2 table

```
  teams standing  q1  q2  q3  q4 finalScore
0   TOR    36-14  16  31  28  31        106
1   IND    32-15  24  35  25  26        110
```

and

```
  teams standing  q1  q2  q3  q4 finalScore
0   CLE     9-40  30  20  30  23        103
1   BOS    30-18  27  38  27  31        123
```

my whole updated  and working code thanks for helping ^^

```
from selenium import webdriver

from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path_to_chromedriver = 'chromedriver.exe' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/scores/01/23/2019'
driver.get(url)

tables = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("linescores-table")

for table in tables:
    team1_quarter_score= []
    team2_quarter_score= []

for line_id,lines in enumerate(table.text.split('\n')):
    if line_id == 0:
        column_names = lines.split(' ')[1:]
    else:
        if line_id % 2 == 1:
            team1_quarter_score.append(lines.split(' '))
        if line_id % 2 == 0:
            team2_quarter_score.append(lines.split(' '))

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'teams': [i[0] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'standing': [i[1] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'q1': [i[2] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'q2': [i[3] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'q3': [i[4] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'q4': [i[5] for i in team1_quarter_score],
                       'finalScore':[i[6] for i in team1_quarter_score]
                                                  }
                     )
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'teams': [i[0] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'standing': [i[1] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'q1': [i[2] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'q2': [i[3] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'q3': [i[4] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'q4': [i[5] for i in team2_quarter_score],
                       'finalScore':[i[6] for i in team2_quarter_score]
                                                  }
                     )
df=df1.append(df2)
print(df)
```

Comment: You are using not the multiple version of locating elements for `tables` in your complete code.

Comment: thanks for reminding that's my error

Answer (score 3):

Your code is only fetching the first table.  You were close with your other attempt.  try:

```
tables = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("linescores-table")
```

which should give you all of the tables to work with. Just wrap the rest of your code inside a for loop that will do the same work on all tables:

```
for table in tables:
    team1_quarter_score= []
    ...
```

Comment: i try your suggestion but it fetch this error  -for table in tables:
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: please update your question with the additional information about the change you made to your code, where the exception is raised, and the stacktrace.  All of this will help us to help you.

Comment: sorry for late reply thanks i have a small mistakes i didn't change the of element to elements. thanks it work a lot